# Symfony Form Ajax filed EntityType returns null

Tags: php, ajax, forms, symfony

I'm working on a form in Symfony with two dependent dropdowns. I was [oriented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66669236/symfony-form-eventlistener-not-triggering/66706155#66706155) into using ajax to populate the second dropdown after a choice is made in the first one.
I've made some decent progress, but now at form validation my selected field in the second dropdown always returns me a null value..

So here is my controller:

```
public function createfact(Request $request, $id, UserInterface $user = null) : Response {
    $form = $this->createForm(FactFormType::class);
    $form2 = $this->createForm(FactForm2Type::class);
    $form3 = $this->createForm(FactForm3Type::class);


    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $form2->handleRequest($request);
    $form3->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        //dd($form->getData());
     
        $fact = new Fact();
        $fact->setDate(new \DateTime());
        $fact->setName('');
        $fact->setUser($this->getUser());
        $fact->addSite($form->get('site')->getData());
        
        //$fact->addAppel($form2->get('appel')->getData());
        $poste = $form2->get('appel')->getData();
        dd($poste);
       
        // ...

}
```

In my FactForm2Type :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('appel', EntityType::class,[
        'class' => Appel::class,
        'placeholder' => 'Sélectionnez un Poste',
        'label' => 'Poste',
        'mapped' => false,
        'required' => true,
        ]);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Appel::class,
    ]);
}
```

And finaly my twig :

```
{% block body %}
<h2>Votre facture :</h2>

{{ form_start(formFact) }}
    {#{{ form_widget(formFact) }}#}
    {{ form_widget(formFact) }}
    {{ form_widget(formFact2) }}
    {{ form_widget(formFact3)}}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Générer la Facture</button>
{{ form_end(formFact) }}



<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        // Clearing the dropdown    
        $("#fact_form2_appel")                                                                          // Getting the DropDown
                        .find('option')                                                                 // Finding <option>
                        .remove()                                                                       // Clearing the options from DropDown
                        .end()                                                                          // Commit changes
                        .append('<option value="" selected="selected">Sélectionnez un Poste</option>'), // Getting message back as first value
        $("#fact_form_site").change(function() {
            var vendor = $('#fact_form_site option:selected').val()
            var DATA = 'id=' + vendor;
            
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                url:  '{{ (path('appelfact')) }}',
                data: DATA,
                success: function(msg){
                    $("#fact_form2_appel")                                                              // Getting the DropDown
                        .find('option')                                                                 // Finding <option>
                        .remove()                                                                       // Clearing the options from DropDown
                        .end()                                                                          // Commit changes
                        .append('<option value="" selected="selected">Sélectionnez un Poste</option>'), // Getting message back as first value
                    $.each(msg, function (i, value) {
                        var html='<option value="'+i +'">' + value + '</option>'
                        $("#fact_form2_appel").append(html);
                    });
                }
            });
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Voilà, I'm kinda lost on why I can't get anything from my EntityType. I must say that just before feeding data to the EntityType, the fonction who is called by the ajax query returns an array of object, so it seems that the problems is to be found after the data are fed into it.

Many thanks in advance to anyone who will be able to help.

Comment: form fact 2 and 3 are really *different* forms, thus when you submit "the" form, you're actually only submitting form 1. thus form fields of formfact2 are ignored in that context and also formfact2 isn't being submitted, since form1 is submitted (and only one can be submitting per request). I think you might want to take a strong look into form events, with which you can modify what form fields are being added to a form depending on submitted/preset data. if you add them as sub forms, the ajax-stuff might still somewhat work ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I knew splitting the form in three part was dirty.. I'm aware of the FormEvents, but I'm struggling with it for a while now. I fought I could get by without them, but it seems that I'll have to learn the hard way..